# How to loop through multi-line sql query and use them in Knex Transactions?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

Newbie in Node and Knex here coming from an RoR background where I need to convert a specific function to Node.js

This is my RoR code:

```
  def self.save!
    update_queries = self.fetch.map{|currency, rate|
      "UPDATE currency_exchange_rates SET rate='#{rate}' WHERE currency='#{currency}'"
    }.join(';')

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(update_queries)
  end
```

So far here's what I  have in Nodejs:

```
static save(new_rates){
      return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        var query = Object.keys(rate).map(key => 'UPDATE currency_exchange_rates SET rate=' + rate[key] + ' WHERE currency = "' + key + '"').join('; ');
    })
  }
```

Here's what the input data looks like:

NEW RATES =

```
'UPDATE currency_exchange_rates SET rate=32102793.12 WHERE currency= "IDR"; 

UPDATE currency_exchange_rates SET rate=0.7822 WHERE currency= "USDGBP"; 

UPDATE currency_exchange_rates SET rate=3189.756317 WHERE currency= "CAD"; 

UPDATE currency_exchange_rates SET rate=152.8 WHERE currency= "USDLKR"; 

UPDATE currency_exchange_rates SET rate=110.818 WHERE currency= "USDJPY"; 

UPDATE currency_exchange_rates SET rate=1.3103 WHERE currency= "USDAUD"'
```

I'm using `Knex.js` to connect to my pg database. How can I execute this all of these using knex? Can I just pass all of the queries in `knex.raw()`? How about `knex.transaction()`? What are their differences?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use `bluebird` `mapSeries`

Comment: Oh thanks I'll check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is knexy way to do it:

```
let retVal = await knex.transaction(async (trx) => {
  for (let key of Object.keys(rate)) {
    let value = rate[key];
    await trx('currency_exchange_rates')
      .update({ rate: value }).where('currency', key);
  }
  return "woo done"; // this value is returned from transaction 
});
```

When dealing with transactions, usually you want to create and run queries one by one to avoid unnecessary buffering of queries before running them through the transaction's single DB connection.

Comment: Thanks for the footnote on why I would want to run queries one by one. I've been trying to understand .transactions too! I don't quite understand why .transaction is still needed when .update can do the job already? Thanks!

Comment: @Reiion please check out from any SQL tutorial or wikipedia etc. what transaction means and why are they used. Basically it allows doing all the updates as a atomic operation where either all of them are committed to database or if even one fails, all of them will be rejected.

Answer (score 3):

```
// [Sequential Update] Commit transaction after each successfully executed query
await knex.transaction(async trx => {
    return Promise.all(Object.keys(rate).map(key => trx('currency_exchange_rates')
            .update({ rate: rate[key] })
            .where({ currency: key })
    ));
});

// [Bulk Update] Commit transaction after all queries have been executed successfully
await knex.transaction(trx => {
    return Promise.all(Object.keys(rate).map(key => knex('currency_exchange_rates')
            .update({ rate: rate[key] })
            .where({ currency: key })
        ))
        .then(trx.commit)
        .catch(trx.rollback);
});
```

Comment: If there are lots of data which needs to be updated, this kind of creating query builders for every query in parallel will use memory very inefficient way. All the query builder are created at parallel, all of them are sent to driver parallel and then driver just buffers them all and will still run those queries sequentially through the single connection of the transaction. Though usually it doesn't matter when updating only small amount of data.

Comment: @MikaelLepistö Thanks for this input, was reading about the difference between both of your answers. I did use yours for simplicity but this reply explains its difference much better. Thanks again!